# how to add active class on centre li

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I would like to Make one “coverflow effect” based on DIV. I decided to use bxslider and everything is working fine but I am not getting the centre "zoom effect" which I would like... You can see an example of what I want here.`http://www.cssjquery.com/coverflow.php`

I'm not sure how to get this effect on the bxslider. Would it be possible if I add extra class on each center LI ? Meaning, whichever "li" is moving to the center, I can add one class "active"... so I can make active transform:sceal etc.

Do you have any ideas on how I can make this happen? Or any other coverflow script you can recommend for this....

Thanks.

Demo

```
http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/cbzmopzb/
```

Comment: What you can do is you give the first slide the `class:active`. Than with the next and prev buttons select the next or prev slide (`li`) by using jquery `.prev()` and `.next();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inbuilt API, like onSlideBefore, onSliderLoad in bxSlider, the animation can be achived..

```
jQuery(function($){

var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
 minSlides: 1,
  moveSlides:1,
  maxSlides: 3,
   pager:false,
  controls:false,
  slideWidth: 360,
  slideMargin: 0,
    onSlideBefore : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){ // your code here 

$(".bxslider li").removeClass("active-slide")
        $slideElement.next().addClass("active-slide")
},
    onSliderLoad:function(index){

$(".bxslider li").eq(1+$(".bxslider .bx-clone").length/2).addClass("active-slide")
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dao1kkfo/2/